# Python Socket Programming Details

Tags: python, sockets

I have a simple server and a client script using python but I don't know what we are doing exactly with the codes. I would be grateful if you could elaborate the meaning and the function of the following lines:

**server.py**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 1234

s.bind((host,port))
```

So what do we do by socket object s.bind()? what do binding mean?

```
s.listen(1)
```

Now we listen for connection but what does the argument for listen mean? It is set to be maximum 5. What is the purpose of this number?

```
c,address = s.accept()
```

Now accept returns a socket object and a tuple which consists of host and port but what I don't understand is this. In client we only use the socket object we create but in server script why are using "c" object to do tasks for client? Why are we creating another socket  object? what is the difference between this "c" and "s" objects?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) for the socket module?

It states the argument is *the maximum number of queued connections and should be at least 0; the maximum value is system-dependent (usually 5), the minimum value is forced to 0.*

You didn't post any specific code, but `c` and `s` are both `socket` objects. One is for the client and one is for the server, it's just a naming convention.

Comment: I read the documentation but didn't understand what is meant by queued connection. I know they are both socket objects I think you missed my question. I am not asking for their naming convention. Why are we creating another socket object on the server script for the client while on the client script only one socket object is enough

Comment: Again, you didn't post any client code so how are we supposed to give you any information on how it works?

Comment: Are you fimiliar with the topic? but anyways:

Comment: import socket    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)            address = ("127.0.0.1",1234)  s.connect(address)

Comment: the rest is the while loop that doesn't matter now